# grouping pandas rows above and below based on specified value

Tags: pandas

Is there a simple way to group pandas dataframe according to a given value. In the code below,the value is 1.5, I want to find the last row with value equal to or greater 1.5 and add a new column 'Group' such that all the rows above that last row are in one group and rows below it are in another group.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
fnd_val = 1.5
A = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
B = [-1.1306,-0.5694,-0.7241,1.8211,1.5555,0.0416,1.9236,0.1944,-0.0204]
df = pd.DataFrame({'Class':A, 'Value':B})
df_srtd = df.sort_values(by = "Class", ascending)

>>>df_srtd
        Class   Value     
    0      1    -1.1306   
    1      2    -0.5694     
    2      3    -0.7241   
    3      4    1.8211    
    4      5    1.5555    
    5      6    0.0416    
    6      7    1.9236    
    7      8    0.19440    
    8      9    -0.0204   

#Desired output


        Class   Value     Group
    0      1    -1.1306   2
    1      2    -0.5694   2 
    2      3    -0.7241   2
    3      4    1.8211    2
    4      5    1.5555    2
    5      6    0.0416    2
    6      7    1.9236    2
    7      8    0.19440   1
    8      9    -0.0204   1

#or if sorting is reversed like below
df_srtd = df.sort_values(by = "Class", ascending=False)


>>>df_srtd
        Class   Value     
    8      9    -0.0204    
    7      8     0.19440    
    6      7     1.9236    
    5      6     0.0416    
    4      5     1.5555    
    3      4     1.8211    
    2      3    -0.7241    
    1      2    -0.5694    
    0      1    -1.1306    



#Desired output
    Class   Value     Group
8      9    -0.0204    2
7      8     0.19440   2
6      7     1.9236    2
5      6     0.0416    2
4      5     1.5555    2
3      4     1.8211    2
2      3    -0.7241    1
1      2    -0.5694    1
0      1    -1.1306    1
```

My approach (using reversely sorted data):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

A = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
B = [-1.1306,-0.5694,-0.7241,1.8211,1.5555,0.0416,1.9236,0.1944,-0.0204]
df = pd.DataFrame({'Class':A, 'Value':B})
df_srtd = df.sort_values(by = "Class", ascending=False)
df_srtd['val_nxt'] = df_srtd['Value'].shift(-1) 

fnd_val = 1.5

conditions = [
        (df_srtd['Value'] >= fnd_val),
        (df_srtd['Value'] < fnd_val) 
        & (df_srtd['Value'] < df_srtd['val_nxt']),
        (df_srtd['Value'] < fnd_val) 
        ]

choices = [ '2', '2', '1']
df_srtd['Group'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default='-99')
print(df_srtd)
```

Result obtained:

```
    Class   Value     val_nxt   Group
8      9    -0.0204   0.19440    2
7      8     0.19440  1.9236     2
6      7     1.9236   0.0416     2
5      6     0.0416   1.5555     2
4      5     1.5555   1.8211     2
3      4     1.8211  -0.7241     2 #All after this should be grouped 1
2      3    -0.7241  -0.5694     2 #This one should have been 1 but is grouped 2
1      2    -0.5694  -1.1306     1
0      1    -1.1306      NaN     1
```

As seen in above result the row with class 3 is put in group 2 instead of 1. I tested by adding more conditions but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
df_srtd['Group'] = df_srtd.Value.ge(fnd_val)[::-1].cummax() + 1

Out[321]:
   Class   Value  Group
0      1 -1.1306      2
1      2 -0.5694      2
2      3 -0.7241      2
3      4  1.8211      2
4      5  1.5555      2
5      6  0.0416      2
6      7  1.9236      2
7      8  0.1944      1
8      9 -0.0204      1
```

---

It is the same on reversed of `Class`

```
Sample `df_srtd_rev`

   Class   Value
8      9 -0.0204
7      8  0.1944
6      7  1.9236
5      6  0.0416
4      5  1.5555
3      4  1.8211
2      3 -0.7241
1      2 -0.5694
0      1 -1.1306

df_srtd_rev['Group'] = df_srtd_rev.Value.ge(fnd_val)[::-1].cummax() + 1

Out[326]:
   Class   Value  Group
8      9 -0.0204      2
7      8  0.1944      2
6      7  1.9236      2
5      6  0.0416      2
4      5  1.5555      2
3      4  1.8211      2
2      3 -0.7241      1
1      2 -0.5694      1
0      1 -1.1306      1
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked very well. It's just what I had been looking for!

Comment: You are right, the same code worked for both orders. Thanks a lot!